# Is $P( (A\cap B)\cap C)$ equal to $P(A\cap C) P(B\cap C)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is $P( (A\cap B)\cap C)$ equal to $P(A\cap C) P(B\cap C)$? In a proof I doubtfully used this equation. Is it correct? But I am not sure about it. Can somebody confirm its validity? If possible, can somebody prove it please?

Comment: what does $(A, B)$ mean? Is it different than $A \cap B$?

Comment: ...and what do you mean by the period in $P(A\cap C).P(B\cap C)$? Should that be a multiplication sign?

Comment: And where is the question? Putting it in the title is not the best way to ask. Anyway, the answer is negative no matter how one interprets the question.

Comment: @SlugPue Yes. I don't think it is different than A ∩ B . So u can take them as similar.

Comment: @skyking yes. Unfortunately my lecturer uses those symbols as he likes and wants. :-)

Comment: @zhoraster I updated the question in proper format. Are u saying that those two terms are not equal?

Comment: It is true if and only if events $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ are independent.

Comment: @Mick A, to be even more precise, this is the definition of independence.

Comment: @MickA; that should be $A\cap B$ is independent of $C$

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I don't think the condition $A\cap B$ independent of $C$ implies $P((A\cap B)\cap C)=P(A\cap C)P(B\cap C)$. E.g. $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ all equally likely, and $\;A=\{1,2\},\;B=\{1,2,4\},\;C=\{2,4\}$.

Comment: @MickA; okay, but $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ aren't independent either

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I didn't mean that example to prove what I claimed, only to disprove what you claimed. :-). In general though, if $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ are independent then $P((A\cap B)\cap C)=P((A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C))=P(A\cap C)P(B\cap C)$.

Comment: @MickA; you're right - i was thinking of $P(A\cap B)\cap C)=P((A\cap B)P(C)$

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No problem. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. The statements like this are rarely true. Say, set $C = \Omega$ and let $A$, $B$ have positive probabilities with $A\cap B = \varnothing$.

Comment: Example is: you flip a coin. $A$ is the case where you get an head, $B$ is tail and $C$ is that the coin lands.

Comment: Thanks all. So anyway I got to there when trying to prove P(A,B|C) = P(A|C)*P(B|C)  Can u guys answer this question too please
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422791/can-pa-bc-pacpbc-be-proved

Comment: @Samitha Chathuranga, the same example works.